# How to run a java project in server which is added as jar in an EAR project

Tags: java, maven, ear

I have created a maven EAR project which is having 3 war files and 2 jar files. I have added EAR in server and able to run web projects. But I need to run the jar project which is added in the EAR. How to run the simple java project in console which is added as jar in EAR?

Comment: Why is that jar project added to the EAR project if it will be run from console?

Answer (score 1):

An **EAR** file has a **ZIP** structure, so you can run **unzip** and the run the jar:

> unzip -d . **path-to-EAR-file** **EAR-internal-path-to-JAR-file**
>
> java -jar **path-to-JAR-file**